# How to get the Firestore collection using Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to backend developing and was trying to write a cloud function that can read, write and edit the data in FireStore. I did the cloud function for write (adding new data). However, I can't get the read working. If you can help me with both read and edit I will be really appreciate. Thank you!

```
Firestore structure:

UserProfile
     |
     +--wWXaLpiOKegAMw6Jhsdf -- {"name": "Danny", "dob": "01/01/2000"}
     |
     |
     +--Ksfe7segse8tPs2pe1Qu -- {"name": "David", "dob": "11/29/1994"}
     |
     |
     +--Udfuwoi8se9g7rdw65dh -- {"name": "Sherry", "dob": "07/21/1997"}
     .
     .
     .


//index.js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const edit = require('./edit.js');
const read = require('./read.js');

exports.edit = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    return edit.edit(request, response);
});

exports.read = functions.https.onRequest((response) => {
     return read.read(response);
});


//read.js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.read = functions.https.onRequest(async (response) => {
    await admin.firestore().collection('UserProfile').get().then(snapshot => {

        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            let arr = {
                name: doc.data().name,
                dob: doc.data().dob
            }
            response.json({result: arr });
        })
    })
})
```

> error: "TypeError: response.json is not a function"

```
//edit.js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    
exports.edit = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
await admin.firestore().collection('UserProfile').get().then(snapshot => {
    
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
       if (request.body.id == doc.id) {
         doc.data().name = request.body.name,
         doc.data().dob = request.body.dob
       } 
            
       const result = {
         name = request.body.name,
         dob = request.body.dob
       }                 
       response.json({result: result});
       })
    })
 })
```

I didn't try out the edit yet so there might be syntax issue like read. I would like to compare the document id for edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass and use both parameters, not just `response`.  JavaScript has positional parameters, not named parameters.  Right now, your code is trying to use a Request object as a Response object, because you named the first Request object as `response`.

Also, you don't need to use the functions SDK to declare your read export.  Just use a normal function.  Only the top-level index export needs to use the functions SDK builder.

index.js

```
exports.read = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
     return read.read(request, response);
});
```

read.js

```
exports.read = async (request, response) => { ... }
```